# Excluding pages from wp_page_listing

Tags: php, wordpress

I have wordpress template.php with listing custom pages. I need to exclude from my listing 2 pages. Is it possible? I'll give what I have maybe somebody knows an answer. Also one guy told me that this code lines will help

```
$args = array(
    'exclude' => array(379,403), 
);

$pages = get_pages( $args );
```

but I'm not a coder and don't know where to isert this lines.

Will be happy to solve this problem . THANKS!

**WHAT I HAVE**

```
 <div id="archive-thumbnails-listing" >
    <?php $pages = get_pages(array('child_of' => 379,403)); ?>

     <?php foreach ($pages as $page): ?>
        <div class="thumb12">
        <div class="thumb20"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'full'); ?></a></div>
    <div class="thumb19"><a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink($page->ID); ?>"><?php echo $page->post_title; ?></a></div>
        </div>

    <?php endforeach; ?>

     </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change

```
<?php $pages = get_pages(array('child_of' => 379,403)); ?>
```

to

```
<?php $pages = get_pages(array('child_of' => 379, 'exclude_tree' => array(1,2,3))); ?>
```

According to [function reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages), `child_of` must be a single post id, and you can exclude multiples posts with `exclude`, or exclude multiples posts and their descendants with `exclude_tree`

Comment: Hmm. this chilf of is a key for listing all child page thumbnails and titles . It is what I want except 2 pages in this listing. If I'll change child of on exclude it will not list child pages anymore. Is There a remove several pages from this child listing? THANKS!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

use this code hopefully it will work.

```
  <?php is_page('42'); ?> or <?php is_page('page-name'); ?>
```